# ng-show does not work inside js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to show or hide a div based on condition from controller I have following code :

```
{
    "mData": "fromWhom",
    "width": "6%",
    "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return '<th check-all="check-all"><div style="border-left:3px solid skyblue;height:76px;float:left" ng-show="isRead"></div><div data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="Check All" class="checkbox c-checkbox" style="margin-left:15px;margin-top:5px;border-left-color:red"><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox"/><span class="fa fa-check conv-table-checkbox"></span></label></div></th>'

    }
}
```

but ng-show does not work from js file

Comment: can you just prepare the fiddle for your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use ng-show when you're writing from script.. can't you use a boolean like this?

```
obj = {
    "mData": "fromWhom",
    "width": "6%",
    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
        var string = '<th check-all="check-all">';
        if(isRead) { 
            string += '<div style="border-left:3px solid skyblue;height:76px;float:left">'; 
        }
        string += '</div><div data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="Check All" class="checkbox c-checkbox" style="margin-left:15px;margin-top:5px;border-left-color:red"><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox"/><span class="fa fa-check conv-table-checkbox"></span></label></div></th>';
        return string;
    }
};
```